# How do I apply a map function to a tensor ? (Tensorflow.js)

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow.js

How can I apply a function to each elements of a tensor like

```
var new_tensor = old_tensor.map(map_function)
```

Comment: @nathan s answer works in all cases, but is slow because the data needs to be transferred of the webgl environment. If you just want calculate the new value out of the old value consider using the tf math methods. It would help if you could provide the `map_function` you want to apply.

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel I need the map function for mutation in the weights of a neural network. So basically, the map function would be to randomize some weights

Comment: If it helps, there is a `tf.layers.dropout`, which exists for exactly this reason: https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.10.0/#layers.dropout

Comment: @Aditya did either of these work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `dataSync` method of `oldTensor` you can get a `TypedArray` which you can map over.

```
var old_tensor_vals = old_tensor.dataSync()
var new_tensor_vals = old_tensor_vals.map(map_function)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `map_function` is specific enough, you can do it simply by using tensor math.

The function below is the implementation of:

```
old => Math.random()>chance?Math.random():old;
```

```js
const old = tf.randomUniform([10], 0, 10);
const chance = 0.75;

const mapped = tf.tidy(() => {
  const max = Math.round(100 * chance);
  const min = max - 1;
  const random = tf.randomUniform([old.shape[0]], 0, 100).floor();
  const ones = random.clipByValue(min, max).sub(tf.scalar(min));
  ones.print();

  const zeros = ones.sub(tf.scalar(1)).neg();
  zeros.print();

  const newValues = tf.randomUniform([old.shape[0]]); //or whatever you want
  //newValues.print();

  return old.mul(ones).add(newValues.mul(zeros));
});

old.print();
mapped.print();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.10.0">
</script>
```